# how to dynamic bind and unbind to event on pusher

Tags: jquery, pusher

i have checkboxes on my site each represent an event name.

i to bind and unbind to event base on the beckboxes, on the site load all checkboxex are checked by default.
this is my code:

```
var pusher = new Pusher('secret');
var channel = pusher.subscribe('latest-news');
$("input:checkbox[name=category]:checked").each(function()
{
    channel.bind($(this).val(), function(data) {
        getNews(data.id);
    });
});

function getNews(ids)
{
    $.post("show", {id: ids})
            .done(function(data) {
        $(".c").prepend(data);
    });
}
```

this code react to checkboxes change:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input:checkbox[name=category]').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        // $this will contain a reference to the checkbox   
        if ($this.is(':checked')) {
            alert('yes');
            channel.bind($(this).val(), function(data) {
                getNews(data.id);
            });
        } else {
            alert('no');
            channel.unbind($(this).val(), function(data) {
            });
        }
    });
});
```

it works fine the problem is when someone uncheck a checkbox then check again what happening is he will get each message twice.
so what is the right way to dynamicly bind and unbind to event without bind twice to the same event.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've seen, the [`channel.unbind` function](http://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_events#unbind-events) takes two parameters: `eventName` and `callback`. The `eventName` is a String and the `callback` parameter is a function reference. When you are calling `unbind` you are likely passing in the correct `eventName`, but you are passing in a reference to a different function so the call will be failing.

To fix this you should have a single function which you can reference and use when binding/unbinding:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input:checkbox[name=category]').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        // $this will contain a reference to the checkbox   
        if ($this.is(':checked')) {
            alert('yes');
            channel.bind($(this).val(), handleEvent);
        } else {
            alert('no');
            channel.unbind($(this).val(), handleEvent);
        }
    });
});

function handleEvent( data ) {
  getNews( data.id );
}
```

References:

- [`unbind` in pusher-js source](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-js/blob/4cabfa066b4e77445faeb525af440e43b5d8ee41/src/events_dispatcher.js#L23)
- [Array.indexOf which compares the function references](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-js/blob/4cabfa066b4e77445faeb525af440e43b5d8ee41/src/util.js#L58)